# Geocoding - Converting an address (in String form) into LatLng in GoogleMaps Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates, street-address

I'm a beginner programmer, took a few courses in university and therefore don't have a complete understanding of the field. I figured I'd give a shot at coding an android application with GoogleMaps API and found the need to **convert a user inputted address (in String format) into Google's complementary LatLng class**, or more precisely, *extract latitude and longitude coordinates in order to input into the LatLng constructor* (JAVA).

My search online in the matter yielded little to no results as the code suggested online is complex given the question at hand is a pretty standard one. I figured there is probably a feature in the GoogleMaps API that would allow me to do so, but I could not find one. For us beginners out here, any pointers on how I could do this ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use Geocoder. Try this code snippet:

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String inputtedAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng resLatLng = null;

    try {
        // May throw an IOException
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(inputtedAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (address.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        resLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return resLatLng;
}
```

Comment: When I tried your code, I got Service not available. I restarted the device and it worked. Thanks +1 !