# It takes almost 1 second to convert String address to lat and lng

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates

I'm using [the following algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42626972/5544859) to convert my string address to latitude and longitude and the string address is getting converted perfectly fine.

I have set two `Log.i(tag, msg)`:

One before the logic,
and one after it's done,

to figure out how long it's taking to convert. I found out that it is taking **ALMOST 1 SEC** just to do one conversion.

Result of loggers:

> 07-03 14:49:50.122
>   4510-4554/com.test.redmI/[com.test.redm.utils.CalculationUtil]= getLngLat begin:
>   Current time is:
>   **Tue Jul 03 14:49:50.122 2018**
>
> 07-03 14:49:50.995 
>   4510-4554/com.test.redmI/[com.test.redm.utils.CalculationUtil]= getLngLat end: Current time is:
>    **Tue Jul 03 14:49:50.995 2018**

In my app, I do have a list of **dynamic** strings that I want to convert. So as the list of address grows, the time to convert does grow as well.

**Question**: Can be achieved faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to take time.  You don't have a list mapping every address in the world on your phone.  You need to call out to Google's webservice, which requires a network request and time for it to process the request.  The solution is to convert them once, store the answer, and use that stored result in the future-  its not like the GPS coordinates of an address change on a non-geological timescale.